# why wireshark shows tls1.2 but it's actually tls1.0

Tags: tls, wireshark

Why does Wireshark show tls1.2 but it's actually tls1.0?

[image: ke]

and sometimes, in almost the same situation it shows tlsV1
[image]

Comment: As seen in the Handshake it is actually 1.2

Comment: You are sure that it is TLS 1.0? Or are you just seeing "TLS version 1.0" and you are wondering what that means?

Comment: I mean the second one. I am wondering why they have a difference value.@schroeder

Answer (score 3):

Because of buggy TLS servers, TLS 1.2 clients send the ClientHello with TLS 1.0 at the record layer protocol_version and TLS 1.2 as the client_version (proposed by the client). A TLS 1.2 server sends TLS 1.2 in server_version back and then they continue with TLS 1.2 flow.

See [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E.1) and [blog posts](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/02/04/oppractices.html) by major implements about version intolerace.

With [TLS 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446), the version mechanism was revised to try a mechanism that is even harder to mess up when implementing, as part of [GREASE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8701) effort to lessen ossification. With TLS 1.3, the protocol layer version in the ClientHello is TLS 1.0 (legacy_record_version), the client_version is TLS 1.2 (legacy_version) and the real version in the version negotiation extension is TLS 1.3 (supported_versions). This is needed to get the connections past crappy middleboxes.